# How to parse string in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, parsing

In db-table I have string like this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Profile is not valid: Given name: can't be blank; Family name: can't be blank>"
```

And I need to extract only error message:

```
Validation failed: Profile is not valid: Given name: can't be blank; Family name: can't be blank
```

record always begins from #

Who could help me?

Comment: Maybe `file.errors` (hash of errors like `errors[:given_name] = "can't be blank"`) is what you are looking for (http://asciicasts.com/episodes/18-looping-through-flash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that for some reason you have saved the result as a string in your database:

```
file.import_entries.last.last_exception.match(/Validation(.*)$/)
```

Comment: To save result in database wasn't my idea) I just have to work with it

Comment: We are not changing the database here... I am just showing how to get what you need: everything after the word 'Validation'

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse it, you just need to ask more specifically:

```
file.import_entries.last.last_exception.to_s
```

What you're looking at is the result of `inspect`, the method called by default in tools like `pry` and `irb`

It's only by convention that `#` indicates the start of the data. A class is free to implement whatever `inspect` method they want, and many produce rather irregular results.

**Update**:

If you've already gone past this point of capturing it cleanly and need to recover the original, then you can do this:

```
file.import_entries.last.last_exception.scan(/#<([^>]+)>/).flatten.join
```

Comment: It's record in data dase: `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Profile is not valid: Given name: can't be blank; Family name: can't be blank`. I have to get from  it only text after `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:`

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. You're looking at an exception in particular, so call [`Exception#to_s`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Exception.html#method-i-to_s) to get just the message. You can also call `message` if that's a better way of expressing it.

Comment: Wait, did this get inserted that way? If so, you might want to capture just the message instead of logging it this way. I've updated the answer with more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

This will extract the errors into a `errors` Hash, similar to how the errors are represented in the original object:

```
s = "Validation failed: Profile is not valid: Given name: can't be blank; Family name: can't be blank"
errors = {}

error_strings = s.split('not valid:').last.split(';')
error_strings.each do |error_string|
  label, message = error_string.split(':')
  attribute_name = label.strip.parameterize.underscore
  errors[attribute_name] = message.strip
end

puts errors
# => {"given_name" => "can't be blank", "family_name" => "can't be blank"}
```